# GameObjects shaking on vuforia image target

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia, android-augmented-reality

I am new to AR and I have uploaded my image target on Vuforia which has 5 star rating. I am trying to put buttons in world space canvas. However, when I run the application on android platform, the gameobjects are very shaky. I have put gameobjects (button and canvas) as child of the image target. Here is a sample video of the final outcome.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1IhKN8O-CqdQW6HNY6VeDoM1dWB8r_ZrT

The device that I am using has been mounted on tripod and still it is shaking.

Comment: Where is your image target? Is it the photo of the room? or the wall tv is hanged?

Comment: Image target is the picture of the actual room where I have multiple objects like tv, chairs, table, etc.

Comment: Well that is the problem most likely. You are using a 2D image but actual marker is 3D which is normally 2D. You can not expect it to track properly. Even if it can this affect will happen because you are placing small objects on top of an enormous marker.

Comment: Any solution to this?

Comment: I dont know what is your use case. If you elaborate more on that then i can offer more help.

Comment: I have multiple objects in a room where I want to place some gameobjects, just like in Video. They all are at different distances from the camera. My approach was to take a picture of the room and place the gameobjects as a child of the image target. The gameobjects that i am using are UI buttons with canvas in world space mode.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187937/discussion-between-piyush-nariani-and-ali-kanat).